# Update Table1 from Table3 joined by Table2

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

Scenario:

Need to SET  [XYZ].[dbo].[ADDRESS].[countrycode] = [ABC].[dbo].[CONTACT].[countrycode]

Table joins:

[XYZ].[dbo].[ADDRESS].[addressid] = [XYZ].[dbo].[ADDRESSLINK].[addressid]

[XYZ].[dbo].[ADDRESSLINK].[contactcode] =  [ABC].[dbo].[CONTACT].[contactcode]

([XYZ].[dbo].[ADDRESS].[addressid] is a primary key in [ADDRESS] but not in [ADDRESSLINK])

*All of these DB's are on the same SQL server.

Tried inner joins with no success.  Wondering if I need to set an alias in [ADDRESS] to be able to update from [CONTACT]?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
  SET a.countrycode = c.countrycode
FROM XYZ.dbo.ADDRESS AS a
INNER JOIN XYZ.dbo.ADDRESSLINK AS al
ON a.addressid = al.addressid
INNER JOIN ABC.dbo.CONTACT AS c
ON al.contactcode = c.contactcode;
```

Why are you table names all upper case and column names all lower case? It makes things SO <sub>HARD</sub> TO <sup>read</sup>. Also please try to reserve the use of `[SQUARE BRACKETS]` for cases where they're actually required. [They] [also] [make] [things] [hard] [to] [read].

Comment: Sorry!  I just copied from the editor we were using which formats things odd.  Thank you for your answer.